# Why does the code that works on iOS devices not work on Android?

Tags: javascript, html

The code below runs the ios operating system. However, you need to click on the Android operating system for the 2nd time. What is the reason of this?

The piece of code that works on iOS systems does not work well on Androids.

Is it because of the viewport meta tag? Do I need to update this?

Can you please help with this problem?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".imageOne").hover(function(){
                    $('.imageOne').css("display", "none");
                    }, function(){
                    $('.imageOne').css("display", "none");
                });
            });
            function myFunction() {
    
            $('.imageOne').removeClass("dis-none");
    
            }
```

Comment: What sense does "hover" make on a touch screen device?

Comment: Please note that `$(document).ready` is deprecated as of jQuery 3.0, if you are using that or a later version: [jQuery docs .ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your question, you are willing to make an HTML element with the class "imageOne" disappear when clicked on.

The jQuery hover function isn't the solution here, especially for touch screen devices.

So I made some modifications to your code; now the imageOne disappears when clicked on, on both devices.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".imageOne").on( "click", function() {
      $('.imageOne').css("display", "none");
    });
    $('.imageOne').removeClass("dis-none");
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply but the imageOne value is not loading at all. in this code.

Comment: Maybe because you didn't add the function myFunction() ?

Comment: I did some changes to the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when you clicked on the image One image before, it was also clicking on the area below. this is not happening right now.